# CUDA Makefile Include Error

Tags: cuda, makefile, include

I'm attempting to write a basic matrix multiplication program using CUDA and C. The code itself doesn't really do anything right now, but should at least compile. After some research on the issue, I've determined that the issue is failure to include CUDA header files, indicating an issue with my Makefile. I'm extremely inexperienced with CUDA (and C for that matter), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Output on command: make matrixMult1

```
c99    -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -c matrixMult1.c -o matrixMult1.o
matrixMult1.c: In function 'main':
matrixMult1.c:77: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaMalloc'
matrixMult1.c:82: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaMemcpy'
matrixMult1.c:83: error: 'cudaMemcpyHostToDevice' undeclared (first use in this
function)
matrixMult1.c:83: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
matrixMult1.c:83: error: for each function it appears in.)
matrixMult1.c:106: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaFree'
make: *** [matrixMult1.o] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
GCC = c99
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := /usr/local/cuda
INCLUDES := -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include
CUDA_LIBS := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -lcudart

matrixMult1.o:          matrixMult1.c
                $(GCC)  $(INCLUDES) -c matrixMult1.c -o $@

matrixMult1:            matrixMult1.o
                $(GCC)  -o $@ matrixMult1.o $(CUDA_LIBS)
```

C Program:

```
//********************************************************************
// matrixMult1.c
//
// A basic matrix multiplication program.
//********************************************************************

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cuda.h"

#define WA 3
#define HA 3
#define WB 3
#define HB WA
#define WC WB
#define HC HA

void initMatrix(float * matrix, int numIndices);

//*************
// Main Program
//*************
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* Set random seed */
    srand(2013);

    /* Compute memory sizes for matrices A, B, and C */
    unsigned int sizeA = WA * HA;
    unsigned int sizeB = WB * HB;
    unsigned int sizeC = WC * HC;
    unsigned int memoryA = sizeof(float) * sizeA;
    unsigned int memoryB = sizeof(float) * sizeB;
    unsigned int memoryC = sizeof(float) * sizeC;

    /* Allocate memory for matrices A, B, and C */
    float * matrixA = (float *) malloc(memoryA);
    float * matrixB = (float *) malloc(memoryB);
    float * matrixC = (float *) malloc(memoryC);

    /* Initialize matrices A and B */
    initMatrix(matrixA, sizeA);
    initMatrix(matrixB, sizeB);

    /* Print matrix A */
    printf("\nMatrix A:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        printf("%f ", matrixA[i]);

    if (((i + 1) % WA) == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf(" | ");
    }
    }

    /* Print matrix B */
    printf("\nMatrix B:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeB; i++) {
    printf("%f ", matrixB[i]);

    if (((i + 1) % WA) == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf(" | ");
    }
    }

    /* Allocate device memory */
    float* deviceMemA;
    float* deviceMemB;
    float* deviceMemC;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceMemA, memoryA);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceMemB, memoryB);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceMemC, memoryC);

    /* Copy host memory to device */
    cudaMemcpy(deviceMemA, matrixA, memoryA,
           cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceMemB, matrixB, memoryB,
               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceMemC, matrixC, memoryC,
           cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    /* Print matrix C */
    printf("\nMatrix C:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeC; i++) {
    printf("%f ", matrixC[i]);

    if (((i + 1) % WC) == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf(" | ");
    }
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Free up memory */
    free(matrixA);
    free(matrixB);
    free(matrixC);
    cudaFree(deviceMemA);
    cudaFree(deviceMemB);
    cudaFree(deviceMemC);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// initMatrix - Assigns a random float value to each indice of the
//              matrix.
//
// PRE:  matrix is a pointer to a block of bytes in memory; numIndices
//       is the number of indicies in the matrix being instantiated.
// POST: Each index of the matrix has been instantiated with a random
//       float value.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void initMatrix(float * matrix, int numIndices) {

    /*
    Loop through the block of bytes, assigning a random float
    for each index of the matrix
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; ++i) {

    /* Assign a random float between 0 and 1 at this byte */
    matrix[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Makefile, it is your code. You have not included any headers from CUDA into your code. Should it really be surprising that the compiler complains about undefined constants?

Comment: Add `#include <cuda.h>` in your code.

Comment: I tried both cuda.h and cuda_runtime.h, both result in a 'No such file or directory' error. I also checked to make sure that the files were in /usr/local/cuda/include/.  I edited the code here on stackoverflow to reflect my changes and the changes to the error output.

Comment: I wonder how did this `matrixMult1.c:81: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cudaMemcopy'` happen. Did you write the output of the make manually? By the way I do not see that you are using the includes  in the compilation. `c99    -c matrixMult1.c`

Comment: Haha, you got me. I did write the output manually. I had to transcribe it from another machine that doesn't have an internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You were not including the appropriate header into your code (which you fixed)
2. Your Makefile is, in fact, broken. It should look something like:

```
GCC = c99
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := /usr/local/cuda
INCLUDES := -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include
CUDA_LIBS := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -lcudart

matrixMult1.o:          matrixMult1.c
                $(GCC) $(INCLUDES) -c matrixMult1.c -o $@

matrixMult1:            matrixMult1.o
                $(GCC) -o $@ matrixMult1.o  $(CUDA_LIBS)
```

[Disclaimer: not tested, use at own risk]

The current problem is that the include path was only specified at the linkage phase of the build.

Note that these changes also preempt the missing symbols error you will get during linkage from not linking with the CUDA runtime library. Note that depending on whether you are using a 32 or 64 bit host OS, you may need to change the library path to `$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64` for the linkage to work correctly.

Comment: I updated the post with the results of this Makefile revision. I'm no longer getting the 'No such file or directory' error, but it's reverted back to the original error state. I'm running 32bit Ubuntu 9.10. I don't think I'm getting a missing symbols error, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

CUDA programs need to be compiled by `nvcc`. While your program does not yet contain any CUDA kernel yet, I believe that is what you want to achieve.

Rename your file from `matrixMult1.c` to `matrixMult1.cu`, remove the `#include "cuda.h"` line (programs compiled with `nvcc` don't need any CUDA-specific includes) and compile with `nvcc` instead of `gcc` (e.g. by setting `GCC = nvcc` at the beginning of the Makefile).